# Php file creation doesn't work

Tags: php, authorization, fopen

My webserver is run as `daemon`. I know about security and so on but please ignore this for now. My problem is that I've done:

```
> chmod 777 /web/htdocs/olivier/wogwog/transit/02.done
> ls -al /web/htdocs/olivier/wogwog/transit
drwxrwxrwx 2 hqfdev hqfdev  36K Jan 17 14:41 02.done
```

So the directory belongs to user `hqfdev` / group `hqfdev`.
Here's my Php code:

```
$tmp_name='/web/htdocs/olivier/wogwog/transit/02.done/caca.txt';
if (($handle=@fopen($tmp_name, 'w'))!==false) {
    fclose($handle);
    error_log('OOOOOOOOOK');
} else {
    error_log('error');
}
```

I keep getting this in my logs:

```
[snip] [:error] [snip] current running = daemon, referer: http://www.blabla/
[snip] [:error] [snip] PHP Warning:  fopen(...): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /blabla.php on line 5, referer: http://www.blabla/
[snip] [:error] [snip] error, referer: http://www.blabla/
```

So the process that tries to create the file is `daemon` and it cant write to a 777 folder that belongs to `hqfdev`. **`(*.*)`**. I'm totally stuck because I've done this a billion times and it worked.
For your information, if I `ssh` my server, log in as `hqfdev` and launch that script "by hand", it works.
What could be the problem (and of course the solution)?

Comment: how do you start your daemon process? I mean, what User? If you use some Cron task for this remember you can (have to) set the correct user/group there.

Comment: @hellcode the directire is commented: `;open_basedir =` so it's not set.

Comment: @lxer This is not a daemon process, this is the Apache Web server and it has been configured to run as daemon/daemon. I've just tried to change it to www-data/www-data and nothing changed.

Comment: in blabla.php at line 5 it's my code `if (($handle=@fopen($tmp_name, 'w'))!==false) `

Comment: - is your disk full?  
- is another process using "caca.txt" (`lsof` may help)  
- do you have concurrency issues?

Comment: @Digifaktur nope, impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution: the parent folder didn't give the right to its children:

---

Configuration that doesn't work

```
$ ls -al /web/htdocs/olivier/wogwog
drwx------ hqfdev hqfdev transit
$ ls -al /web/htdocs/olivier/wogwog/transit
drwxrwxrwx hqfdev hqfdev 02.done
```

---

Now the configuration that **works**:

```
$ ls -al /web/htdocs/olivier/wogwog
drwxr-xr-x hqfdev hqfdev transit
$ ls -al /web/htdocs/olivier/wogwog/transit
drwxrwxrwx hqfdev hqfdev 02.done
```

...pure Unix lack of knowledge...